# Oracle Apex- How to place label on top of checkbox

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Apex 21.2 and have a checkbox item.

It doesn't have the alignment attribute for the label.

Currently label for checkbox is coming towards its right but i want to align it to top.

How can this be done?

Comment: Without checking the HTML structure of the page from browser console, it would be not possible to answer your question. But you can play with CSS attributes of the checkbox's HTML elements to achieve it.